# KDE - Monitor doesn't go into power save mode

Tags: xorg, kde, display

I'm having intermittent issues with KDE not going into powersave, ie: turning the monitor off and suspending the system.

In MENU / ENERGY SAVING I've set kde to turn monitor off after ten minutes, suspend session after twenty minutes.

I've not been able to discern that anything is running whilst it fails (and not running when it doesn't fail).

- What can I do to check for failures or conflicting
  applications/services etc to resolve this issue?

---

- What can I do in the interim, where my screen is on indefinitely, no lock screen, no monitor power down and no (auto) system power down.

I've seen a few temp solutions, I can SSH in and do the following:

1 - This only works if the session is NOT locked.  Using the mouse/keyboard, re-awakens monitor etc (desired outcome).  Attempting whilst locked results in `xset: unable to open display ""`:

```
loginctl lock-session
xset dpms force off
```

2 - This works whether locked or not, but using keyboard/mouse does not bring monitor back to life and requires `vbetool dpms on` to resume operation.

```
vbetool dpms off
```

3 - This does not work at all, resulting in `setterm: cannot (un)set powersave mode: Inappropriate ioctl for device`

```
setterm -powersaveon
```